# Using $user_profile inside a module

Tags: users

Another developer has left me a non-functional page inside a module with a lot of dependencies tied to $user_profile, which does not exist in the scope of this module. Is there a way I can use $user_profile (which arguably has the calls necessary) over having to make changes to make $user (which does work, strangely) on this page?

This is the code block that loads the template in question. The rest of this module is basically a hook_menu overload with aforementioned methods. No other calls are made to $user_profile here.

```
function generic_user_player_messages($usernumber) {
  global $user;
  $userID = $user->uid;

  if (is_numeric($usernumber) && ($account = user_load($usernumber)) && ($userID == $usernumber) && (in_array('member', $user->roles)) || (in_array('administrator', $user->roles))) {
    return theme('generic_user_player_messages');

  } elseif ($userID != $usernumber) {
      return array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => t("This is not the profile you are looking for"), 
      );

  } else {
    return drupal_not_found();
  }
}
```

And a segment of the code from the .tpl.php

```
        <?php
        //dsm($user_profile);
        //dsm($user);

        $user_picture = render($user_profile['user_picture']);
        if (strlen($user_picture) > 0) {
            print render($user_profile['user_picture']);
        } else {
            ?>
            <div class="user-picture">
                <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="/sites/all/themes/generic/profile/generic-avatar.png" />
            </div>
        <?php }
        ?>
```

Comment: May you show the code? Without seeing it, it's quite impossible to answer your question. `$user_profile` is not a global variable used from Drupal, but it is a variable passed to [user-profile.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user-profile.tpl.php/6).

Comment: I can't show much code, but i'll show the pertinent snippets in an update. Hold on.

Comment: Is the template file user-profile.tpl.php? It is not possible to answer your question, without to know from where `$user_profile` comes.